# Python3 splitting a list using a word+character

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

I have a list and I want to split it's items into their own sections if it matches a word together with a semi-column. This will make much more sense when you look at the below code and desired outcome.

```
list = [
    'Size: 20inches. Weight: about 1.2kg',
    'Length: pretty long. Body: is plastic.',
    'For all ages. Comes with box'
    ]
```

Desired outcome:

```
list = [
    'Size: 20inches.',
    'Weight: about 1.2kg',
    'Length: pretty long.', 
    'Body: is plastic.',
    'For all ages. Comes with box'
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_data = [
    'Size: 20inches. Weight: about 1.2kg',
    'Length: pretty long. Body: is plastic.',
    'For all ages. Comes with box',
]

output_data = []

for line in input_data:
    s = re.split('(\w+ *:)', line)  # Split line by '<word>:'
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        # This is an empty string. Ignore
        if not s[i]:
            i += 1
            continue
        # We found a 'Key:'. Get the 'Value' and add it to output
        elif s[i].endswith(':') and i+1 < len(s):
            new_item = s[i] + s[i+1]
            i += 2
        # We found a lone string. Add it to output
        else:
            new_item = s[i]
            i += 1
        output_data.append(new_item.strip())

print(output_data)
```

Output:

```
['Size: 20inches.',
 'Weight: about 1.2kg',
 'Length: pretty long.',
 'Body: is plastic.',
 'For all ages. Comes with box']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split()`:

```
x_lst = [
    'Size: 20inches. Weight: about 1.2kg',
    'Length: pretty long. Body: is plastic.'
    ]

print([x.split('. ') for x in x_lst])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['Size: 20inches', 'Weight: about 1.2kg'], ['Length: pretty long', 'Body: is plastic.']]
```

**EDIT**:

If you want a flattened list:

```
 res = [x.split('. ') for x in x_lst]
 print([item for items in res for item in items])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Size: 20inches', 'Weight: about 1.2kg', 'Length: pretty long', 'Body: is plastic.']
```

**EDIT 2**:

I see you have changed the desired output, with the new Input:

```
res = [x.split('. ') if x != x_lst[-1] else [x] for x in x_lst]     
print([item for items in res for item in items])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Size: 20inches', 'Weight: about 1.2kg', 'Length: pretty long', 'Body: is plastic.', 'For all ages. Comes with box']
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `'For all ages. Comes with box'` wasn't last item in the list. So it's just a hacky solution which works for specific input. Also you are loosing the dots at the end of the string which is probably not a big deal but clearly not what OP wants.

Comment: @Asocia The last EDIT 2, has that case covered.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Try adding one more item to the input. And you will see `'For all ages. Comes with box'` will be splitted into 2 items.